# SignalR and HttpParameterBinding

Tags: asp.net, signalr, owin

Web API allows to populate (bind) controller method's parameter using custom logic.
For this purpose one have to create a class derived from `HttpParameterBinding`.
(For example - I would like to bind a header value to some method parameter)

So far so good.

Now, I would like to do the same with SignalR Hubs server methods.
Does SignalR have a similar facility?